# Tagging should use before trigger or after trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger, dml

I have a column `STag`, data type is `bit`, and another column `SFile` with a data type of `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

When web application is calling to update this table, my trigger shall update `STag = 1` when `SFile` has data, reversely, update `STag = 0` when `SFile` is emptied.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [STag_UPDATE] 
    ON [Employee] 
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
        DECLARE @EMPLOYEEID AS INT;
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT @EMPLOYEEID = EmployeeId 
        FROM inserted

        UPDATE EMPLOYEE 
        SET STag = CASE 
                       WHEN LEN(SFile) > 0 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                    END
        WHERE EmployeeId = @EMPLOYEEID
    END
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ENABLE TRIGGER [STag_UPDATE]
    GO
```

My question here is: is it appropriate to write the trigger this way? Or I shall write the trigger using `instead of`?

Comment: You're making classic trigger 101 mistake - assuming that `inserted` will only hold one record, when it fact it could contain 0-N records.

Comment: @DaleK Can you explain more? Im newbie on mssql trigger.

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call.

Comment: Whether to use an `AFTER` trigger or an `INSTEAD OF` trigger is a design decision that only you can make - `instead of` triggers require you to handle the entire update though, so keep that in mind. But in your case an `after` trigger will cause an infinite recursion loop which needs to be handled.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add your logic to the update statement itself rather than needing a trigger?

Comment: @DaleK so for my scenario here. how you suggest the trigger would be written? example?

Comment: I would have the update method of your app call a stored procedure which calculates `SLTag` and then carries out a single update statement on your table without needing a trigger. Or I would do as marc_s explains below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why even bother with a trigger?? You can **easily** create a **computed column** that contains that information and needs no manual intervention to be kept "up to date":

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ADD IsEmpty AS CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(SLFile) = 0 THEN 1 WHEN SLFile IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
```

So if `SLFile` is NULL or has a `DATALENGTH` of 0 - then `IsEmpty` will show a value of `1` (true) - otherwise `0` (false).

No messy trigger, no need to constantly update - SQL Server will take care of it all for you, automagically, behind the scenes